# Using async/await inside for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

How can I use async/await inside a for loop?

This is my code:

```
export default (req, callback) => {
  // ...
  compliance.forEach((rule, index) => {
    let response = await waRuleOverview(req, run.id, rule.id);
    // handle the response
  });
}
```

This is how I define the `waRuleOverview` function:

```
export function waRuleOverview(req, runId, ruleId) {
  var def = deferred();

  setTimeout(function() {
    const apiToken = req.currentUser.apiToken;
    const payload = {
      'Authorization': 'api_key ' + apiToken
    }

    const options = {
      'method': 'get',
      'gzip': true,
      'headers': payload,
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'json': true,
      'url': 'api-url'
    }

    request(options, (error, response, body) => {
      def.resolve(body);
    });
  }, 50);

  return def.promise;
}
```

It throws this error in the console:

> await is a reserved word

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45485626/node-js-call-calback-function-inside-for-loop) one which I'm trying to figure out how to solve it.

Comment: I tried, but I still get that error..

Comment: @Andreas Why? OP does not use `await` inside `waRuleOverview` but returns a Promise

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It depends on how you want your async code to be executed: sequentially or in parallel. Anyway, you'd need to add `async` keyword to use `await`.

```
// sequential
export default async (req, callback) => {
  // ...
  for(const [rule, index] of compliance.entries()) {
    const response = await waRuleOverview(req, run.id, rule.id)

    // handle the response
  }
}

// parallel
export default async (req, callback) => {
  // ...
  const responses = await Promise.all(compliance
     .map((rule, index) => waRuleOverview(req, run.id, rule.id))
  )

  // handle responses
  responses.forEach(response => {
    // ...
    // handle response here
  })
}
```

And finally, if you don't really want your handler to return a Promise but just want it to perform some async actions for side effects.

```
export default (req, callback) => {
  // ...
  compliance.forEach(/* add */ async (rule, index) => {
    // to use await inside
    let response = await waRuleOverview(req, run.id, rule.id);
    // handle the response
  });
}
```

But this approach is actually an anti-pattern since it breaks promise chains: bad for composability, error handling and such.